# How to get a cog to rotate on button click, then accept if clicked set number of times?

Tags: javascript, css, html, button, rotation

I'm trying to create a basic rotating cog puzzle (with just the one cog). The cog rotates 90degrees each time it's clicked. There is a seperate button to input that answer to check if correct. If the cog is rotated into the wrong position and the button is clicked, then the user is returned to the previous url. If the cog is rotated into the correct position, then the button is clicked, the location changes to a second url.

I'm trying to combine a clickCount function with code to rotate the cogs on each click. So it will both rotate the cog and also add/count clicks (starting with a value of 2), so when the button is clicked it will carry out either case 1 (if the clicks are a multiple of 4) or case 2 (if the clicks are not a multiple of 4). But I can't even getting the cog to rotate once. For some reason it's creating a second cog rather than letting me click/rotate the main one.

If anyone can help me just with the rotating part, then I'll create a new question for the clickCount bit as each part is a specific issue on its own. But I've included it here for reference.

```js
$('input').click(function() { //* When user clicks on first image //
  var img = document.getElementById("innercog"); // *select second img which is id "innercog" //
  if (img.hasClass('north')) { //* if second image has class "north", rotate... and so on *//
    img.attr('class', 'west');
  } else if (img.hasClass('west')) {
    img.attr('class', 'south');
  } else if (img.hasClass('south')) {
    img.attr('class', 'east');
  } else if (img.hasClass('east')) {
    img.attr('class', 'north');
  }
});

// Counts the number of times cog is clicked and stores it as n 
var clickCount = 2;

function clickHandler() {
  clickCount + 1; /* start with value of 2 and add 1 each time cog is rotated/clicked */
  missing code here /* Store clickCount value as n */
}

// When tryunlock button is clicked, checks if stored clicks value is a multiple of 4 and navigates to one of the two urls depending if correct 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#multiclick').click(function() {
    multiclick();
  });
});

var clickedCount = n; /* pull this value from the above function */

function multiclick() {
  if (clickedCount == multiple of 4) {
    window.location.href = "entranceroom.html";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "maindoor.html"; /* go to next page */
  }
}
```

```css
.north {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* Safari / Chrome */
}

.west {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.south {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.east {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<div id="wrapper" div class="toshow" style="display:none;">
  <!-- div class added for fade in content -->
  <div style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;">
    <img src="doorpuzzle1b.png" style="position:absolute" width="980" height="650" alt="Maindoor" />
  </div>

  <!-- Button to return to main door -->
  <div id="enterbutton" style="position:relative;top:260px;left:20px">
    <a href="maindoor.html"><img src="cogarrowleft.png" alt="Courtyard" width=97 height=97 border=0></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Button to rotate cog -->
  <div style="position:relative;top:41px;left:311px">
    <img class="north" id="innercog" src="innercog.png" onclick="clickHandler()" width=370 height=370 border=0><input type="image" src="innercog.png">
  </div>

  <!-- Button to try unlocking door cog -->
  <div id="tryunlock" style="position:relative;top:41px;left:311px">
    <button type=button onclick="multiclick()" alt="" style="width:97px; height:97px; border:0; background-color:red;" /> </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: So now I answered I get your second born too? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to see if I understood

1. `if (clickedCount%4===0)` it is a multiple of 4
2. Be consistent - you have an inline click and a clickhandler but have a far too generic *click any input*
3. Your HTML was invalid, the button tag was closed too early also the whole thing had display:none

```js
var directions = ["north", "west", "south", "east"],
  clickedCount = 0;
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#innercog').click(function() { //* When user clicks on first image //
    $(this).removeClass(directions[clickedCount % 4]);
    clickedCount++; // we do not reset, just keep adding
    $(this).addClass(directions[clickedCount % 4]);
    console.log(clickedCount,directions[clickedCount % 4]);
  });

  // When tryunlock button is clicked, checks if stored clicks value is a multiple of 4 and navigates to one of the two urls depending if correct 
  $("#tryunlock").on("click", function() {
    if (clickedCount % 4 === 0) {
      console.log(clickedCount,"Entrance"); // remove the next comment when happy
      // window.location.href = "entranceroom.html";
    } else {
      console.log(clickedCount,"maindoor"); // remove the next comment when happy
      // window.location.href = "maindoor.html"; /* go to next page */
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.north {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* Safari / Chrome */
}

.west {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.south {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.east {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<div id="wrapper" class="toshow">
  <!-- div class added for fade in content -->
  <div style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;">
    <img src="doorpuzzle1b.png" style="position:absolute" width="980" height="650" alt="Maindoor" />
  </div>

  <!-- Button to return to main door -->
  <div id="enterbutton" style="position:relative;top:260px;left:20px">
    <a href="maindoor.html"><img src="cogarrowleft.png" alt="Courtyard" width=97 height=97 border=0></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Button to rotate cog -->
  <div style="position:relative;top:41px;left:311px">
    <img class="north" id="innercog" src="innercog.png" width=370 height=370 border=0><input type="image" src="innercog.png">
  </div>

  <!-- Button to try unlocking door cog -->
  <div style="position:relative;top:41px;left:311px">
    <button id="tryunlock" type="button" style="width:97px; height:97px; border:0; background-color:red;">Open</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just woke up and saw this. Thank you for having a go at it (and yes, I will clone any offspring to create a personal army of tiny slaves if you can get this to work)! However, so far the above code just leads to the attached (and I've isolated this from the rest of the site to see if any other components were causing an issue, but so far that hasn't helped). 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gohpvo5f7c78gee/cog1.png?dl=0

Comment: What am I looking at? I see an image. Does it give errors?

Comment: (The cog doesn't animate when clicked on and the Open button doesn't navigate anywhere).

Comment: A picture does not help me much. Press F12 and look in the console

Comment: Ok, I've got it rotating now. But the console log is showing 'maindoor' regardless of whether the click count is a multiple of 4 or not. And it doesn't actually navigate to the maindoor url (or the entranceroom one). So for 2 clicks (which should result in a click total of 4), the console log shows "1 west maindoorpuzzle.html:50:5
2 south maindoorpuzzle.html:50:5
2 maindoor maindoorpuzzle.html:59:7"

Comment: I need to see this in action somewhere - you could set up a jsfiddle.net and share

Comment: I just need to see one

Comment: So in your codepen I get EntranceRoom in the console when I click open on the 4th click/north

Comment: Yeah, that's incorrect. The starting value of the clickcount should be 2. So the first correct input would be two more clicks (which aligns the cog correctly). Then every 4 clicks after that would also align the cog correctly.

Comment: I think I've realised how to fix it actually. The bit "var directions = ["north", "west", "south", "east"], clickedCount = 2;" changing it from 0 to 2 seems to have fixed it (I think).

Comment: When I change to `clickedCount = 2;` then it does what you say it should https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXrGYK

Comment: For the last bit... how do I get rid of the extra cog that's appeared on the page (where it says 'Submit Query' in the Codepen?

Comment: Come on. Remove stuff you do not need `<input type="image" src="innercog.png">` I already told you that is a submit button

Comment: Sorry... I'm very very new to coding. The obvious stuff isn't obvious to me yet. But that's working perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help. I know I'm some random person on the internet, but I really appreciate it! I've been trying to get my head around that for ages!

Comment: No problem. If you tidy your code and try to not add too many things without removing the old stuff you will have an easier time :)

Comment: I'm still at that stage where if I spend a two weeks working on a bit of code and 10% works correctly, then I'm scared to delete any of the old code in case it all breaks! :D But getting there, It's a massive learning curve. But thank you again for your help!